# How to create module for Rest Api , Magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Who can help, how to create a structure in the custom module for Rest Api ?

Answer (score 0):

When I had that question, walking through this tutorial helped me:
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-api/

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to use some Magento classes in your API, this tutorial provides an example of using dependency injection to access those classes functions.

https://www.thirdandgrove.com/creating-custom-rest-api-magento2

Answer (score 0):

This will help you: [Sample extension](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-api/)

For more reference : [Magento 2 devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html)